# Как центрировать текст в текстовом виджете в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, select, текст

У меня есть текстовый виджет

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wm_title("cloth")
root.geometry("500x500")
l = Text(root, width=46, bg="White",relief = "solid", font="Arial 9",height=1,bd=1)
l.configure(state='normal')
l.configure(state='disabled')
l.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Я хочу центрировать текст, но если я выберу текст, то будет выбран только текст, пробел не будет выбран

Comment: я уже пробивал: text_widget.insert(END, user, 'tag-center') но видно пробелы

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример кода с центрированием
import Tkinter as tk

```
root = tk.Tk()

T1 = tk.Text(root)
T1.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
T1.insert("1.0", "text")
T1.tag_add("center", "1.0", "end")
T1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: прочитай комментарий, это не работает пробел выделяется